# Cisco ASA 5520 - Create local VPN pool

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

Can I create a local ip pool with a /22 mask to support 1022 VPN hosts on an ASA or limited to a /24 mask per subnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASA VPN address pools can be a /22 (or larger) and function correctly.

The limitation of how many of those addresses can actually be active at any one time is based on the hardware in use. The 5520 supports up to 750 concurrent VPN peers per the [datasheet](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/security/asa-5500-series-next-generation-firewalls/product_data_sheet0900aecd802930c5.html).

Answer (score -1):

I dont see a reason why it wouldnt work with 22 prefix.
Not sure the ASA has the hardware to deal 1000 vpn connections.

Comment: 5520 will support up to 750 VPN peers, so there will be some unused addresses in the pool, but the /22 will work fine.

Comment: @cpt_fink, you should post that as an answer and not a comment to another answer.

Comment: Was just clarifying the answer's uncertainty about the # of vpn connections... i'll repost as an answer though.